# Sequelize connection for read replicas, how to connect to different ports?

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js, read-replication

I am trying to access MySQL databases from Sequelize. The MySQL setup is such that read nodes have different port compared to write. I could only find this from docs page. [Sequelize read replica connection](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/docs/usage/) . What would a correct json connection file look like with mentioned port differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/sequelize/#new-sequelizedatabase-usernamenull-passwordnull-options) you can have different write and read connection configuration. The doc was just a bit painful to find.